# Find next in VBA and display data on userform each time

Tags: excel, vba, userform

First of all I must admit that I am quite new in programming and Visual Basic in general. I try to learn by reading a book and looking at tutorials so you'll have to excuse my low level of competency.
So I made a User-form so that I can add data to an excel database. I managed to make a search function so that I can find the data that I want (more specific the person's Last Name), and at the same time display all the relevant data based on the search result on my User-form. The problem is that in some cases I have multiple same Last Names and I would like to be able to find them all. Right now I can only find the first search result but can't search any further then that. So I would like the same "Button" to search for the next match if there are more than 1 matches and at the same time, display the whole data on my User-form each time. If it can't be done with the same "search" button it's ok if it needs an extra button to be inserted in the User-form.
Thank you all for your time and your possible contribution to me solving this problem!

EDIT:
There seems to be another problem which I don't understand. If there are multiple same values in "ROW B" it finds the last one i.e. searches from the bottom and up. Shouldn't it be searching from top to bottom?
Why is this happening?
Thanks again!

This is my Code:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
        
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
        Dim lr As Long
        lr = sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        
        
     txtSearch.Text = UCase(txtSearch.Text)
       
        
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("B:B"), Me.txtSearch.Text) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No person was found with this Surname!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"
            Call Reset
            Call UserForm_Initialize
            txtSearch.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        For i = 2 To lr
        If sh.Cells(i, "B").Value = txtSearch.Text Then
            txtSurname = sh.Cells(i, "B").Value
            txtRN = sh.Cells(i, "A").Value
            txtOnoma = sh.Cells(i, "C").Value
            txtPatronimo = sh.Cells(i, "D").Value
            txtDate = sh.Cells(i, "E").Value
            '...{more values and data entries at this point}...
        End If
     Next i
     Me.txtSurname.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: As a suggestion: store the cell address where the last value occurrence was found somewhere in the workbook (maybe in a cell in a hidden worksheet).

Comment: ...or as a global variable in your userform.

Comment: ... or a hidden control (label or textbox) on UserForm. I would suggest you to add a button (FindNext) on the UserForm.

Comment: I think I get a hint of what you are saying but not completely. I like the idea of adding a new button (FindNext) but i am a little lost as what the code will be so I can go from "i" to "i+1". Maybe I need some sort of loop until I reach i again?
Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: Re _Shouldn't it be searching from top to bottom_.  It is.  But it's overwriting the results each time it finds a match.   That's why the last found result is left in place. To return the first found item, add `Exit For` inside the `If`, just before the `End If`

Comment: Thank you chris neilsen! That works and it makes perfect sense. Thank you for explaining it to me. Now unfortunately back to the original problem...